# Instantiate overloaded class templates depending on parameter type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a `Container<T>` class that holds elements of type `T`. `T` may or may not be a reference type, and I want to treat them differently (i.e., a `Container<int>` and a `Container<const int &>` have different implementations). I've tried something like

```
template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_reference<T>::value>::type>
struct Container {
    ...
};

template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_reference<T>::value>::type>
struct Container {
    ...
};
```

But the compiler complains about redefinition of `Container`. Why is `enable_if` not working here? Can I work around it?

Comment: Just partially specialize for reference like [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9186f74f51a87f12)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thank you, that works. But why doesn't `enable_if` work in this case?

Comment: There ain't no such thing as overloaded classes, only overloaded functions. You can't define two class templates with the same name, `enable_if` or no `enable_if`